# Please merge [isolated-storage] [isolatedstoragefile] into [isolatedstorage]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge Stackoverflow tag [isolated-storage](/questions/tagged/isolated-storage) and [isolatedstoragefile](/questions/tagged/isolatedstoragefile) into [isolatedstorage](/questions/tagged/isolatedstorage).

All three refer to Microsoft .net framework System.IO.IsolatedStorage. I don't have enough reputation to create synonym proposal.

Comment: [isolatedstorage] is harder to read than [isolated-storage].  Are you sure that you don't want the master tag to be the hyphenated version?

Comment: @KevinVermeer [isolatedstorage] has 233 questions while [isolated-storage] has 52, and [isolatedstorage] matches the .net namespace. But actually I'm OK both way, as long as they are merged.

Comment: +1 A half year later, still not merged.